# Only update all duplicate keys in Mysql table and not add new entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to just update duplicate keys and NOT add new entries to the Urldup table.

Here is the query i am using but this also adds new entries.

```
INSERT INTO urldup (url, date, projectname)
Select url, date, projectname
From sample_temp s1
ON Duplicate key update date = now();
```

I want to just update the duplicate keys and not do an insert of any fresh data.

The url column is a unique key.

Comment: `update sample_temp set date = now() where keyCol = yourValue`

Comment: Hi this don't work because it updates columns on date but it does this for all entries i just want to do it for duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out:

```
INSERT INTO urldup (url, date, projectname)
Select url, date, projectname
From sample_temp s1
Where url = s1.url
ON Duplicate key update date = now();
```

Comment: This will also insert new rows. There is no reason to use `INSERT` when you want to update only.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do an update, then use `update`:

```
UPDATE urldup u
    SET date = now()
    WHERE exists (select 1 from sample_temp t where u.url = s.url);
```

This assumes that the duplication is based on the field `url`.  You can add more conditions in the `where` clause if other fields are involved.